# PyhtonAnywhere Exceeded Max User Connections in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I have a Python Flask web site running in PythonAnywhere. It runs fine for some time and then I start getting  "User 'felipeavl' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 3) "

I am using SQLAlchemy and setting pool_recycle as advised in PythonAnywhere forums :

```py
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=280)
```

I am also closing the session in all my flask methods, although SQlAlchemy was supposed to manage the connections, if I am not wrong:

```py
def listarEmissores():
    session = DBSession()
    emissores = session.query(Emissor).all()
    session.close()
    return render_template('listar_emissores.html', emissores=emissores);
```

In my local MySql database everything runs fine. Am I missing any other configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to email support at Pythonanywhere to get them to reset the connections on their end (as I had to). Otherwise, you will see I had the same issue (and my solution) at the bottom of the following page: 
[How do I fix this Gets server error, which is causing display issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466829/how-do-i-fix-this-gets-server-error-which-is-causing-display-issues/56479993#56479993)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I am not sure that asking them to reset my connection would solve my problem. I say it because after some minutes receiving the 'max_user_connections' error the queries start working again. So I am guessing that the connections are eventually being closed, but not at the moment that I am explicitally closing them ...